# Image IO - Why when converting Image to red scale, blue scale does it result in black images?

Tags: image, file-io, javax.imageio

I have a problem with my current programming project. The assignment calls to take an image from my computer (I use one of the sample pictures that the computer provides) and convert it to grayscale, green, red, and blue. I wrote the code for the program and it successfully converts the first two pictures (the original => grayscale and the original => green), but when it converts to red and blue, it produces an all-black image (what should happen is the picture should be converted from original => red and original => blue along with the previous two conversions, gray and green). Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Prog3a 
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{

    BufferedImage img = null;
    File f = null;

    //read image

    try
    {
        f = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Penguins.jpg");
        img = ImageIO.read(f);
    }
    catch(IOException exception)
    {
        System.out.println(exception);
    }

    //get image width and height

    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();

    //convert to grayscale

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            int p = img.getRGB(x,y);

            int a = (p>>24)&0xff;
            int r = (p>>16)&0xff;
            int g = (p>>8)&0xff;
            int b = p&0xff;

            //calculate average
            int avg = (r+g+b)/3;

            //replace RGB value with avg
            p = (a<<24) | (avg<<16) | (avg<<8) | avg;

            img.setRGB(x, y, p);
        }
    }

    //write image

    try
    {
        File toGray = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\CS108toGray");
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", toGray);
    }
    catch(IOException exception)
    {
        System.out.println(exception);
    }

    //convert to green image

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
      for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
      {
        int p = img.getRGB(x,y);

        int a = (p>>24)&0xff;
        int g = (p>>8)&0xff;

        //set new RGB
        p = (a<<24) | (0<<16) | (g<<8) | 0;

        img.setRGB(x, y, p);
      }
    }
    //write image

    try
    {
      File toGreen = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\CS108toGreen");
      ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", toGreen);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    //convert to red image

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            int p = img.getRGB(x,y);

            int a = (p>>24)&0xff;
            int r = (p>>16)&0xff;

            //set new RGB
            p = (a<<24) | (r<<16) | (0<<8) | 0;

            img.setRGB(x, y, p);
        }
    }

    //write image

    try
    {
      File toRed = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\CS108toRed");
      ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", toRed);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    //convert to blue image

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            int p = img.getRGB(x,y);

            int a = (p>>24)&0xff;
            int b = p&0xff;

            //set new RGB
            p = (a<<24) | (0<<16) | (0<<8) | b;

            img.setRGB(x, y, p);
        }
    }

    //write image

    try
    {
        File toBlue = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\CS108toBlue");
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", toBlue);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

How can I modify my program so that the red and blue image converter correctly converts the image to its respective colors? As a beginning programmer, any and all advice/suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Advice: Don't catch the exception, print a message and continue your program (it will just crash later, with a less meaningful exception). Instead, let the exception bubble up and terminate your program. A best practice in programming is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). You have a lot of loops that are very similar. Try to refactor the code. Also note, for extracting the R, G & B channels, you don't need any shifts, only a bitmask (ie. for blue: `p = p & 0xFF0000FF`). See if that makes any difference. Finally, JPEG isn't a good format for storing alpha. Try PNG.

Comment: @haraldK thank you for the advice!